# SQL JSON Help and Query Help needed

Tags: sql, json

Good day Stackoverflow,

I have found myself in a bit of a weird query situation. You see, I have to come up with a stored procedure that returns a data set like so;

```
[
"TestCase1": {
    "SetText": {
        "Element":"Username"
        "Value":"123456"
    },
    "SetText": {
        "Element":"Username",
        "Value":"Admin"
    },
    "OnClick": {
        "Element":"SubmitButton"
    },
    "Login": {
        "Username":"admin",
        "Password":"123456"
    }
}
]
```

As you can see the data set is held together by the TestCase1 which is in reference to a Table Column Name.  Test.Name

Follow by, the function name holding multiple objects. 
Each function has its Keys be the parameter name and the keys values are the parameters values

So in this example, Test Case 1 has 4 actions

1. SetText("Username", "123456")
2. SetText("Password", "Admin")
3. OnClick("SubmitButton")
4. Login("Admin","123456")

The problem is; the query list below I can't alter it to the way I have the JSON above

```
SELECT TD.ID, F.[Name] AS [Function], P.[Name] AS [Parameter], E.[Name] AS [Data] FROM [QA].[TestData] TD
LEFT JOIN QA.[Parameter] P ON P.ID = TD.ParameterID
INNER JOIN QA.[Function] F ON F.ID = P.FunctionID
INNER JOIN QA.[XREF_Parameter_Element] XPE ON (P.ParameterTypeID = 1) AND (XPE.ID = TD.DataID)
INNER JOIN QA.[Element] E ON E.ID = XPE.ElementID
UNION ALL
SELECT TD.ID, F.[Name] AS [Function], P.[Name] AS [Parameter], XPV.[Value] AS [Data] FROM [QA].[TestData] TD
LEFT JOIN QA.[Parameter] P ON P.ID = TD.ParameterID
INNER JOIN QA.[Function] F ON F.ID = P.FunctionID
INNER JOIN QA.[XREF_Parameter_Value] XPV ON (P.ParameterTypeID <> 1) AND (XPV.ID = TD.DataID)
ORDER BY TD.ID

FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('TestCase1')
```

Here is what the query above turns out to be

```
{
"TestCase1":[
    {
        "ID":1,
        "Function":"SetText",
        "Parameter":"Element",
        "Data":"Username"
    },{
        "ID":2,
        "Function":"SetText",
        "Parameter":"Value",
        "Data":"123456"
    },{
        "ID":3,
        "Function":"SetText",
        "Parameter":"Element",
        "Data":"Username"
    },{
        "ID":4,
        "Function":"SetText",
        "Parameter":"Value",
        "Data":"Admin"
    },{
        "ID":5,
        "Function":"OnClick",
        "Parameter":"Element",
        "Data":"SubmitButton"
    },{
        "ID":6,
        "Function":"Login",
        "Parameter":"Username",
        "Data":"Admin"
    },{
        "ID":7,
        "Function":"Login",
        "Parameter":"Password",
        "Data":"123456"
    }
]

}
```

Is anyone able to help me out. I am more than willing to share contact information to be more clear. This is just ripping my brain apart.

Comment: TestCase1 inside SetText object expecting for the Query ? correct?

Comment: The top root object can be ignored. TestCase1 Was just a holder. We do not need it for this example

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? SQL is just a query language, not the name of a specific product.

Comment: Ssms is the ide I am using